# SQL issue: cannot construct data type date some of the arguments have values which are not valid

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am working on an Excel project where I use SQL query to extract some data from SQL Server 2012.

When I select the data without filters, everything works fine.

However, when I use the `DATEFORMATPARTS` formula below, I get this error:

> Cannot construct data type date some of the arguments have values which are not valid

`A.[Invoice date]` is the correct date format.

```
WHERE 
    A.[Customer] NOT IN ('100', '398', 399) 
    AND A.[Item] LIKE '1%'
    AND A.[Invoice date] >= DATEFROMPARTS(Year(DATEADD(yyyy, -1, GETDATE())), Month(DATEADD(yyyy, -1, GETDATE()) >) + 1, 1)
```

I've tried a lot of different stuff, but without luck.

Any guesses what is wrong in the above.

Thanks a lot in advance!

/ T

Comment: You have a `>` sign in the expression.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the input

it was precisely the month: 12 + 1

that was the issue! thanks

Comment: You can use MONTH(12 + 1), or DATEADD(MONTH, 1, 12).  But be careful when using DATEFROMPARTS, since 12+1 also increases the year by +1.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `>` sign in the expression is a typo

```
Month(DATEADD(yyyy,-1,GETDATE()))+1
```

This is resulting `13` which is a invalid month so you are getting that error.

Removing `>` and `+1` from Month part will fix your issue

```
select DATEFROMPARTS(Year(DATEADD(yyyy,-1,GETDATE())),Month(DATEADD(yyyy,-1,GETDATE())),1)
```

If you are trying to find last year last month first date then

```
select datefromparts(year(getdate())-1,12,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have problems with that month calculation if you get a december and it adds a month to get month 13 of the year, this obviously isn't valid. If you want 11 months ago then do this;

```
DATEFROMPARTS(Year(DATEADD(YYYY,-1,GETDATE())),Month(DATEADD(mm,-11,GETDATE())),1)
```

Which (today, December 2016) returns '2015-01-01'